# how to check isinstance of iterable in python?

Tags: python, iterable, isinstance

consider this example?

```
p = [1,2,3,4], (1,2,3), set([1,2,3])]
```

instead of checking for each types like

```
for x in p:
   if isinstance(x, list):
      xxxxx
   elif isinstance(x, tuple):
      xxxxxx
   elif isinstance(x, set):
      xxxxxxx
```

Is there some equivalent for the following:

```
for element in something:
  if isinstance(x, iterable):
      do something
```

Comment: The simplest approach is just to try iterating over it and catch the exception if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 18):

You could try using the `Iterable` ABC from the `collections` module:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: p = [[1,2,3,4], (1,2,3), set([1,2,3]), 'things', 123]

In [3]: for item in p:
   ...:     print isinstance(item, collections.Iterable)
   ...:     
True
True
True
True
False
```

Comment: Importing `Iterable` from `collections` is deprecated and will break in Python 3.8+. Instead, import from `collections.abc`, e.g. `from collections.abc import Iterable`.

Comment: If you wish to use `collections.abc.Iterable` as a generic type (e.g., `Iterable[int]`) in Python 3.8 or earlier, you must also do `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: @BallpointBen I think you're confusing `collections.abc.Iterable` with `typing.Iterable`.

Comment: @cz Python is changing so fast these days... Take a look at [Pep 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/), it says importing types that exist in `collections.abc` from `typing` is deprecated; importing them from `collections.abc` is the right way to do it in Python 3.9+, and in Python 3.7+ with `from __future__ import annotations`.

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the object has `__iter__` attribute in it, to make sure if it is iterable or not.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = {1, 2, 3}
c = (1, 2, 3)
d = {"a": 1}
f = "Welcome"
e = 1
print (hasattr(a, "__iter__"))
print (hasattr(b, "__iter__"))
print (hasattr(c, "__iter__"))
print (hasattr(d, "__iter__"))
print (hasattr(f, "__iter__") or isinstance(f, str))
print (hasattr(e, "__iter__"))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
True
True
True
False
```

**Note:** Even though Strings are iterable, in python 2  they dont have `__iter__`, but in python 3 they have it. So, in python 2 you might want to have  `or isinstance(f, str)` as well

Comment: This fails for strings, which are iterable but don't have `__iter__`.

Comment: @Mark i think they have.

Comment: `>>> str.__iter__
<slot wrapper '__iter__' of 'str' objects>`

Comment: @MarkReed I added a note for string part.

Comment: @aIKid In python 3, we have but not it python 2

Comment: @aIKid - the attribute is there in Python 3, but not in 2.x

Comment: @Downvoter please check my answer now and let me know if it is still wrong.